# Allocation of already allocated memory

Tags: objective-c, c, memory, allocation

I am developping an Objective-C (iOS) application which use very big-sized arrays (size > 10 000) in a C-based part of the app.

At a moment of the execution, i make a malloc of a little struct i made, i have the message :

```
      malloc: *** error for object 0x6505a4: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed
```

The adress given by the message is already taken by an array i used before this call :

```
 write in address : 0x6505a0  - im_x[12]  // im_x is my array 
 write in address : 0x6505a8  - im_x[13]  // im_x is my array
```

Why does iOS try to allocate memory already used ?

Any help is welcome :)

Thanks !

Comment: iOS doesn't try to allocate in-use memory.  There will be a bug in your code that causes this error.  Can you create a minimal test case and edit your question to include that code please?

Comment: How do you create your array?

Comment: What Stephen said; I'd bet a dollar that you are overrunning the end of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  malloc: *** error for object 0x6505a4: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed
```

is a message which tells me that you corrupted the data structures of the heap somewhere (buffer overflow, underflow, some other strange magic).

Try to debug your program with `valgrind` (if this is an option) or if not try to isolate memory curruption suspicious code and debug it with valgrind, you must have somewhere a bug which overwrites anywhere some esential datastructures.

**Into the heap**

To explain this strange error message here is some funny ASCII art

- F : Free block/byte
- M : Memory managment structures

  FFFFFFFF

now the application allocates some memory twice (A and B)

we get something like

```
AMBBBMFF
```

if we write now here in memory

```
AMBBBMFF
 ^
here
```

we currupt the datastructures of the heap, and because of that the checksum of A or and B is wrong so it emits an errormessage.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of you, i found my problem :

One of algorithms asked to have a special size and wasn't test it (it's not my own code), so it writed out of the array.

Answer (score -2):

if your program makes lots of malloc , it can reash limit of the memory which is dedicated for your program. You might probably free memory when you no longer need it. Try increasing your program memory limit.